# Why does URL return null here when trying to get a resource inside Jar?

Tags: java, file, url, jar, nullpointerexception

I have this Jar file..

`core.jar`:

```
META-INF/...
com/...
config
  myLog4j.xml
schema
```

The class that is trying to read/load is in `com/my/company/MyLogging.class`

The code is this, inside `MyLogging` class:

```
URL myUrl = MyLogging.class.getResource("/config/myLog4j.xml");
```

`myUrl` is `null`. Its not returning the resource/file.

**Edit:** Included the picture of path.

[image]

tar output:

```
     0 Fri Oct 24 16:15:10 CDT 2014 META-INF/
   122 Fri Oct 24 16:15:08 CDT 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed Oct 22 16:40:26 CDT 2014 com/
     0 Wed Oct 22 16:40:26 CDT 2014 com/my/company/..
     .....
     0 Wed Oct 08 11:20:42 CDT 2014 config/
     0 Wed Oct 08 11:20:42 CDT 2014 config/email/
     0 Wed Oct 08 11:20:44 CDT 2014 schema/
     0 Wed Oct 08 11:20:42 CDT 2014 schema/alliance/
     0 Wed Oct 08 11:20:44 CDT 2014 schema/tibco/
  7972 Fri Oct 24 16:15:08 CDT 2014 com/my/company/MyLogging.class
  2045 Wed Oct 08 11:20:42 CDT 2014 config/myLog4j.xml
   400 Wed Oct 08 11:20:42 CDT 2014 config/email/bodyDashtemp.st
  1583 Wed Oct 08 11:20:42 CDT 2014 schema/Castor-XMLJavaScript.txt
 18958 Wed Oct 08 11:20:44 CDT 2014 schema/tibco/TIBCO_EventSchema.xsd
```

Edit:

I am running it from command line. JUnit test.

**Edit:** More info...

This (`core.jar`) is a dependency Jar file. It is included in the classpath of the JUnit test class file.

This `MyLogging.class` is used in the class that is being unit tested. And the class I am unit testing is actually a Struts2 action class. Its a unit test and not an integration test. Meaning, this action class is treated as a regular class instead of Action class.

**Edit:**

`Manifest.mf` contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: pwa6460_26sr7ifx-20131203_01 (SR7) (IBM Corporation)
```

Comment: Nope. The control jumps from that line to Catch block.

Comment: I'd like to see the whole try-catch statement and the stack trace.

Comment: I guess, you are right. I am using one more statement below that with the myUrl. Thats throwing null. But question again is why is it not returning the file

Comment: How do you launch your app and are you certain that the jar contains those files?

Comment: Yes, I double checked the jar contents using jar explorer and its there like I listed above.

Comment: Post the output of `jar tvf core.jar`, verbatim.

Comment: @JBNizet I uploaded an image

Comment: Well, the image makes it look like the file is named ' myLog4j.xml', with a leading white space. Why not post the output of `jar tvf core.jar`, as I asked?

Comment: Post it all: how you launch your app, the relevant code snippet where an exception occurs, and the exception stack trace.

Comment: How _specifically_ (**post the exact command**) are you running it? And please complete your post with the other information we asked for.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis posted more info. that could be of help. JUnit runs the class that is being unit tested (from ant).

Comment: What does the Class-path entry of the manifest in the *main* JAR file look like? And where are these JAR files located when you execute?

Comment: @EJP. There is no main jar. This is one of the jars in dependency. A single class is being run with this jar along with other jars. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

There is another `.jar` containing the `MyLogging.class` who loads earlie. Because a Classloader can load a class only once, the first `MyLogging.class` is used, where its jar does not have the resource.

Comment: This would be my first assumption as well.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if the class is loaded twice/from different location?

Comment: The underlying classloader may give you a hint. Try `((URLClassLoader)MyLogging.class.getClassLoader()).getURLs()` to get a list of jars loaded from the Classloader or the parent Classloader.